# ERROR in Read query using n AWS AppSync Chat Starter App written in Angular "Can't find field allMessageConnection"

Tags: aws-appsync

const message: Message = {
conversationId: conversationId,
content: this.message,
createdAt: id,
sender: this.senderId,
isSent: false,
id: id,
};
this.appsync.hc().then((client) => {
client
.mutate({
mutation: createMessage,
variables: message,

```
      optimisticResponse: () => ({
        createMessage: {
          ...message,
          __typename: "Message",
        },
      }),

      update: (proxy, { data: { createMessage: _message } }) => {
        const options = {
          query: getConversationMessages,
          variables: {
            conversationId: conversationId,
            first: constants.messageFirst,
          },
        };
        // error on below line
        const data = proxy.readQuery(options);
        const _tmp = unshiftMessage(data, _message);
        proxy.writeQuery({ ...options, data: _tmp });
      },
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log("mutation complete", data);
      console.log("mutation complete", data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("Error creating message", err));
});
Analytics.record("Chat MSG Sent");
```

}

ERROR
errorHandling.js:7 Error: Can't find field allMessageConnection({"conversationId":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","first":100}) on object {
"me": {
"type": "id",
"generated": false,
"id": "User:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"typename": "User"
}
}.

[image: ERROR ON CONSOLE]